# ViewPager missing from com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library

Does anyone know if ViewPager class has been removed from revision 28 of the support library? Looks like the whole view package is gone.

Comment: According to the docs, that dependency should include all v4 packages, but try implementing `com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0` instead anyway.

Comment: @TheWanderer According to the docs, yeah. But obviously it does not. I have tried your suggestion but it did not help. Sorry.

Comment: Can you show your entire app-level Gradle config?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the support libraries have been moved to androidx:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/

Sorry for the confusion. Though I am getting `Error inflating class androidx.core.view.ViewPager`, this should ultimately be the answer.

Comment: Btw, this was happening because migrating to androidx automatically changed the layout widget to androidx.core.view.ViewPager instead of androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager as it did in the code. Changing to androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager in the layout fixed this error.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove implementation

> 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3@aar'

this library if you  are using this then it is working fine not an any issue.